# bash script to rename following a pattern in subdirectories and make a copy

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to do an iterative renaming of certain files in all directories.

```
homefolder/folder1/ouput/XXXXX_ab.png
homefolder/folder1/ouput/XXXXX_abcdefg.png
homefolder/folder2/ouput/XXXXX_ab.png
homefolder/folder2/ouput/XXXXX_abcdefg.png
homefolder/folder3/ouput/XXXXX_ab.png
homefolder/folder3/ouput/XXXXX_abcdefg.png
...
homefolder/folder500/ouput/XXXXX_ab.png
homefolder/folder500/ouput/XXXXX_abcdefg.png
```

I want to get the folder name (ex. **folder1**, **folder2**, ... **folder500**) and pass it to the two png files as a prefix and remove those five **X**s at the beginning of each file.
The pattern of those png files are:

```
XXXXX_ab.png
XXXXX_abcdrfg.png
```

so only the first five characters are different in each subdirectory, which will be replaced by the name of its parent directory, those folder names.

the results will be:

```
homefolder/folder1/ouput/folder1_ab.png
homefolder/folder1/ouput/folder1_abcdefg.png
homefolder/folder2/ouput/folder2_ab.png
homefolder/folder2/ouput/folder2_abcdefg.png
homefolder/folder3/ouput/folder3_ab.png
homefolder/folder3/ouput/folder3_abcdefg.png
...
homefolder/folder500/ouput/folder500_ab.png
homefolder/folder500/ouput/folder500_abcdefg.png
```

at the end of renaming, create a copy of these two newly renamed files inside another folder in the homefolder, for example **all_png_folder**.

```
find . -iname "*_ab.png" -exec rename _ab.png folder1_ab.png '{}' \;
find . -name "*_ab.png" -exec cp {} ./all_png_folder \;
```

Comment: What does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start, the copying at the end should be a trivial addition.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=$(find . -type f -name "*_ab.png" -or -name "*_abcdefg.png")

for file in $files; do
    foldername=$(cut -d '/' -f 2 <<< $file)

    # The name of the png-file minus the leading xxxxxx
    pngfile=$(basename "$file" | cut -d '_' -f 2)
    destinationdir=$(dirname "$file")
    mv $file "$destinationdir/$foldername"'_'"$pngfile"
done
```

## Demo

```
$ tree        
.
├── folder1
│   └── ouput
│       ├── foo_bar.png
│       ├── xxxxx_abcdefg.png
│       └── xxxxx_ab.png
├── folder2
│   └── ouput
│       ├── xxxxx_abcdefg.png
│       └── xxxxx_ab.png
└── rename.sh

4 directories, 6 files
$ ./rename.sh
$ tree
.
├── folder1
│   └── ouput
│       ├── folder1_abcdefg.png
│       ├── folder1_ab.png
│       └── foo_bar.png
├── folder2
│   └── ouput
│       ├── folder2_abcdefg.png
│       └── folder2_ab.png
└── rename.sh
```

Comment: I have other png files in the folder so i would like to apply this action only to "_ab.png" and "_abcdefg.png" files not all the rest of png files. However these two files always have the same number of characters in the beginning of their file names, for example XXXXX, always five characters.